# Update UI-Element from different thread and different class

Tags: wpf, vb.net, dispatcher

I don't quite understand the Dispatcher. I'm working on a WPF-application.

Following scenario:

I call an asynchronous method from code-behind. (Method is in another module, but public. I can't access UI-elements from there tho.)

Now I want to change a ListBox from that method, but obviously I can't access that UI-element from this method, which makes the Dispatcher kind of useless since I get the error that the UI-element isn't declared.

So I can only call BeginInvoke from the Code-Behind? Doesn't make much sense, no?

The dispatcher code I have in my asynchronous method, outside the mainWindow-class:

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, CType(Sub() AddLogFileText(stringLogFile), SendOrPostCallback))
```

Comment: You can only access private members from the same class. And that makes perfect sense. This is nothing to do with involving dispatcher. It's usual to return results from an async task back to the ui thread and then make calls will change UI properties. And if that's in some other class entirely then expose a public method from that class that itself can access it's private members. Or use some sort of a bridging object/mechanism like prism event aggregator or mvvmlight messenger.

Comment: But whats the point of the Dispatcher then? How does it work? A lot of examples online just show Dispatcher code with ui-elements in it. But that obviously doesn't work, since you can' access ui-elements from there.  For Example:
   `Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
    DispatcherPriority.Background,
    new Action(() => this.progressBar.Value = 50));` How do they access the progressBar?

Comment: The point of the Dispatcher is that very bad things happen if you need to try to harden the UI against modification from several threads; thus none of the .NET UI technologies try.  They make it illegal to try to modify from anywhere other than the UI thread.  Thus, the dispatcher is a way for a non-UI thread to run something on the UI thread (and update the UI).

Comment: Public vs. private is a separate issue from the Dispatcher.  If you're having public vs. private issues, the Dispatcher is a red herring, your code wouldn't compile without the dispatcher either.